# Update using Entity Framework 1 (EF1) - on saveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to increment a counter which is stored in the DB.

So this requires me to do and update using Entity Framework 1 (EF1).

I am doing something like this:

```
  CounterTBL OrderCounter = MyRepository.CounterTableDetails("ORDERID"); 

  Booking Booking = new Booking();

  Booking.BookingAdminID = User.ID;
  Booking.BookingStatus = 2;

  OrderCounter.CounterFLD = OrderCounter.CounterFLD + 1;

  using (var ctx = new WhygoContext())
  {
      ctx.AddToBookings(Booking);
      ctx.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Booking is inserted fine, but I expected the existing record to be updated, which is was not.

A search around StackOverflow and the web shows that I should do something like this:
    ctx.CounterTBL.Attach(OrderCounter);
    ctx.ApplyCurrentValues("CounterTBLs", OrderCounter);

Or similar, but my intellisense doesn't like this and it doesn't build so I assume these are only a part of EF 4.

I am sadly stuck with EF 1. Is there a way to do this.

I'm pretty new to this stuff, so maybe I'm not going about this in the right way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're inserting `Booking` you are creating a new instance of the context and call save changes only on that instance. Your `OrderCounter` was loaded from repository and I guess it used different context instance. You should share the context instance between both operations or you will have to call `SaveChanges` on both context.

Btw. your code is not very reliable if it is run in ASP.NET because concurrent clients can store the same counter.